# three.js gamma correction and custom shaders

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am not quite sure how THREE.js handles gamma correction internally.
It seems that to enable it the only thing you have to do is to set the following flags on the renderer object:

gammaInput = true;
gammaOutput = true;

However when you are writing your own custom shaders and fetching a color from a texture, do you still have to convert the color into linear space or does THREE.js transforms the texture before uploading it to the GPU (when gammaInput is set to true)?

Similarly, when determining the final color in your shader, do you have to convert it to gamma space or is there a post process effect that THREE.js automatically applies (when the gammaOutput is set to true) ?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1488

Answer (score 3):

Three.js will not map your texture to another space **before uploading to the GPU**. Everything is done in-place in the shader using chunks.

**To convert input value to linear:**

As an example, take a look at how Three.js handles the `map` property [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/map_fragment.glsl.js#L6). You will basically see this line:

```c
texelColor = mapTexelToLinear( texelColor );
```

And `mapTexelToLinear` is basically created in the [WebGLProgram.js file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.js#L71).

You get the idea.

To sum up, you can basically include [this chunk](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/encodings_pars_fragment.glsl.js) at the top of your shader:

```c
#include <encodings_pars_fragment>
```

And then you need to decode your texel according to the space your texture is in. Example if you use an sRGB texture:

```c
vec4 color = sRGBToLinear(texel);
```

**To output a gamma corrected value:**

You also need to include `encodings_pars_fragment` at the top of your shader:

```c
#include <encodings_pars_fragment>
```

You then need to include the chunk that modifies the frag color automatically. Take a look at [this line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/meshphysical_frag.glsl.js#L115).

By including the chunk `encodings_fragment` at the end of your custom shader, it will automatically map your fragment according to the parameters you used on the `THREE.WebGLRenderer`.

To understand why this work, you can look at the [encodings chunk](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/encodings_fragment.glsl.js), containing only:

```c
gl_FragColor = linearToOutputTexel( gl_FragColor );
```

And then you can take a look at the [WebGLProgram.js file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/b6445caf38582eac02e54088c438a31f8df65df9/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.js) to understand how the `linearToOutputText` function works. This works basically the same way as the texel decoding.

Hope this is useful!

Answer (score 0):

While I believe that https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1488 answers your first question, your second question remains unanswered.

I've found that

`renderer.gammaOutput = true;`

doesn't do anything when you're using a custom shader for your material. You can test this by enabling `gammaOutput` and setting `gammaFactor` to an extreme value. The built-in materials respond to this, but your custom shader does not.

So yes, you'll need to handle gamma yourself in this case, either by modifying the output color, or by adding a post processing step after you've done all you rendering in linear space.